# How to program GET parameters

Tags: google-chrome, get

I've been trying to make some custom auto-hotkey shortcuts to make my job easier. As I've been digging around I found that to make these shortcuts you must use "GET parameters" that basically pass on information to a website.
I'm trying to learn about these and from what I've read I kind-of understand what they are but I can't seem to put them in practice. Let's take an example:

```
http://www.te.com/commerce/alt/product-compliance.do
```

This website is for checking the certification of certain products we purchase. I would like to automatically fill in the part number & just display the search results. From inspecting the website I came up with the following edited URL, however, it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
http://www.te.com/commerce/alt/product-compliance.do?TE_alt_partentry=MyPartNumberOnClipBoard
```

but that doesnt seem to yield anything. It just loads the regular webiste. (I got the TE_alt_partentry from inspecting the website source, it is the id for the input part)

Answer (score 0):

Getting texts and parameters only work with basic programs like notepad in AHK, Not with browsers.